# React unity WebGL not working on React JS project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Hey there trying to make my Unity WebGL export work on my React JS project but for some reason is not working I'm using the following [React Unity WebGL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unity-webgl) version (react-unity-webgl@7.x  # For Unity 2018 and 2019 (Active LTS)) and I have followed the instructions accordingly to the version I'm using, someone ran into the same issue than me and asked a question in the [GitHub](https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl/issues/131) and I followed what they said which is basically to put the unity folder in the public folder but still is not working. Anyone has any idea of how to fix this ?

This is how I have my folder structure:

[image]

And this is the 2 codes I have try (which they are basically the same):

Code A:

```
import React from 'react'
import Unity, { UnityContent } from "react-unity-webgl";

let unityContent = new UnityContent(
  "Megaman/Build/Megaman.json",
  "Megaman/Build/UnityLoader.js"
);

function MegamanGame() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Is not working</h1>
          <Unity unityContent={unityContent} />
        </div>
      
    )
}

export default MegamanGame
```

Code B:

```
import Unity, { UnityContent } from "react-unity-webgl";
export default function Megaman() {
    let unityContent = new UnityContent(
        "Megaman/Build/Megaman.json",
        "Megaman/Build/UnityLoader.js"
    );
    return (
        <div><Unity unityContent={unityContent} /></div>
    );
}
```

And this is how it renders

[image]

Take in mind I have try the path in 2 ways either `"Megaman/Build/Megaman.json"` or just `"/Build/Megaman.json"`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and writing an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered here anyone looking: https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl/discussions/299

Code was fine just needed to add "/Megaman/Build/Megaman.json" and "/Megaman/Build/UnityLoader.js".

And keep in mind the "UnityContent" has been reworked into "UnityContext" from version 7.x to 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

you have to move your unitybuid folder as child of Public file, as this /public/Build/yourfiles.json

i am havinbg problems after that, it runs well on local host, but when building on a hosting sites, it doesnt loading for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It does not have to be "/public/Build/yourfiles.json" developer told me as long as the route/path is correctly it should work and it did.

In my code I have the Page in the SRC and the build in the public however this is how I have to write it up: "/Megaman/Build/Megaman.json" because I made another folder inside the public (that way I can separate the multiple games I wanna add)

Comment: Ah yeah, of coruse... if you have more folders you have to add them in the path,... but what i meant is that the project folder have to be inside the public folder. 
  Glad it worked